# How to make assignment inside the Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var events = [
    {id: 100,url: "mc.jsp?id=" + id},
    {id: 200,url: "mc2.jsp?id=" + id},
    {id: 300,url: "mc2.jsp?id=" + id}
]
```

When run, the url equals `mc.jsp?id=undefined`,
so how can assign the id (100) to the url to get the value of `mc.jsp?id=100`?
And also make the second url as `mc2.jsp=200` and third one `mc2.jsp？id=300`
so I cannot make assignment outside the array.

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. Show us more of the loop and we'll be able to give better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access other properties in an object literal on constructions. You get an `undefined` because you have no variable `id`. You will need to use:

```
var id = 100;
var events = [{"id":id, "url":"mc.jsp?id=" + id}];
```

or:

```
var event = {id: 100};
event.url = "mc.jsp?id=" + event.id
var events = [event];
```

but you could define a getter:

```
var events = [{id: 100, get url() { return "mc.jsp?id="+this.id; } }];
```

which is very complicated and difficult to understand. Maybe it's better to do something like this:

```
function MyEvent(id, mc) {
    this.id = id;
    this.mc = mc;
}
MyEvent.prototype.getUrl = function() {
    return "mc"+this.mc+".jsp?id="+this.id;
};

var events = [new MyEvent(100, ""), new MyEvent(200, "2"), ...];
```

However, there should be no such problem. If you hardcode the numbers, why don't you hardcode the urls? If you don't want the redundancy, just don't store the id two times and append it each time you need it.

Comment: but it is array, i cannot assign it outside

Comment: that way, every item i need one fucntiuon inside the arrat?

Comment: Things start to complicated when `prototype` comes in...But it is convenience!

Comment: Why do you want it at all? Isn't it redundant then, if it's always the same?

Comment: what is prototype? need to import some package?

Comment: @Bergi - Hey look, found something interesting. The first one is `mc.jsp` and the others are `mc2.jsp`. You might want to change something?

Comment: @juggernaut: No, it's pure JavaScript... There are good and many tutorials about that on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `id` because its a name of a property, not a variable.
You can do:

```
var ids = [100,200,300];
var events = [];
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length;i++){
    events[i] = {id: ids[i],url: "mc.jsp?id=" + ids[i]};
}
```

Comment: but different item in array will have different value, so i cannot make all of them 100

Comment: You have already hard coded 100 in your code. Seems that you have another problem which you haven't mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var id = 100, events = [{id: id, url: "mc.jsp?id=" + id}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like  it.

```
var event = {
 'id': 100,
 'url': 'mc.jsp?id=' + event.id
}

var events = [];
events.push(event);
```